# jQuery count on table length returning incorrect value

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to count the number of rows in my table.  When I test via the console, here's what I get:

```
$("#rule_summary").html();
"
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><b>Actions</b></th><th><b>Contact Type</b></th><th><b>Contact Number</b></th><th><b>Call Order</b></th><th><b>Text</b></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
        <td> 
         <a href="" class="delete">Delete</a>        
        </td>
        <td> Home Number</td>
        <td> 4442</td>
        <td> 1</td>     
        <td> no </td>           
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td> 
         <a href="" class="delete">Delete</a>        
        </td>
        <td> M Number</td>
        <td> 28507</td>
        <td> 2</td>     
        <td> yes </td>          
    </tr>
        </tbody>

"
```

And here's what the count is (console debug as well)

```
$("#rule_summary").length
1
```

I've been reviewing the code to make sure my table is formatted properly... I can't see anything wrong with it.. but maybe another pair of eyes will find something. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this

```
$("#rule_summary tr").length
```

Remember this will include your table header row.
Working fiddle here :
http://jsfiddle.net/fBsLv/

Comment: Always use the `find` instead of complex selectors for this cases. It is much more faster in terms of performance. http://jsperf.com/fdsafasdfafsdaashgfjgfj

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong. You are getting a `1` because there is only one element with the id `#rule_summary`.

If you want to count the number or rows (`tr`) you should:

- Select all the rows
- Count the number of selected elements

For it you could do:

```
$('#rule_summary').find('tr').length
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$("#rule_summary tr").length
```

if you want to count all rows including header row

OR this if you want just data rows (no header)

```
$("#rule_summary tbody tr").length
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UHF6Y/